# Texture only works in solid view version 2.7

Tags: texturing

I used a texture map with multiple textures and set them up in the UV editor while in solid view, but when I switch it to textured view to check my lighting the textures appear as lines and the floor has the whole texture map even though I set each face with a different texture. What is going on and how can I fix it?[image: here is what the problem looks like]

Comment: in the material tab make sure the UV Co ordinants are set to UV